# Dependencies in Android Gradle project (Android Studio)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The project structure is:

```
project_name
|--app (main Android application module)
|--secured (Android application module)
```

**app** module *does not* depend on **secured** module. But **secured** module depends on **app module**.

Here's snippet from **secured** build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
  <...>
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':app')
  compile files('libs/libA.jar')
  compile files('libs/libB.jar')
}
```

So everything seems to be fine, AS doesn't put any warnings. But when I run **project_name:secured [assemble]** from Gradle tasks panel in AS, I get hundred of warnings. All of them refer to **app** module, like I forgot to add a dependency of **app** module. As a result I can't get apk file of **secured** module.

What's wrong? Where might I have made a mistake?

**UPD1**

```
/Users/artm/Documents/Projects2/project_name/secured/src/main/java/com/companyname/app/vps/secured/SecuredClass.java:3: error: cannot find symbol

import com.companyname.app.vps.ISecured;
                          ^
symbol:   class ISecured
location: package com.companyname.app.vps

<and about hundred of errors such this>

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':secured:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

**UPD2**

```
include ':app', ':shared', ':secured'
```

**UPD3**
Is it possible that Android library module depend on Android app module?

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful when you show the stacktrace. I guess you checked your settings.gradle in your root project?

Comment: Post your settings.gradle

Comment: @TheEnd please, see UPD1 and yes, settings.gradle is placed in the root

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti please see UPD2

Comment: Are you sure that com.companyname.app.vps.ISecured exist?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sure, it's placed in **app** module, which's invisible from **secured** module. **app** module uses ISecured without any trouble.

Comment: try to clean, resync and rebuild

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti tried many times. May several Android application modules exit in one project? Is it possible in principle?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have one Android application module (which uses `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in its build file) depend on another Android application. You can only depend on Android libraries (`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`) instead.

If both these modules need to generate APKs, then you should take the code in your main **app** project and refactor it out into an Android library and have both **app** and **secured** depend on it.

Comment: Could Android library module depends on Android application module?

Comment: Besides, **app** module contains a package com.company.abc and **secured** module contains exactly the same package. Needless to say, that these two packages contains different sources. And sources from **secured** module depend on sources of **app** module. Maven solves this situation perfectly.

Comment: No, a library can't depend on an Android app module.